# Why is a random part of the code highlighted?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

We have an online editor made by monaco-editor, here is the link: https://v3.10studio.tech/#/formula-editor-addin?app=formula-editor-addin. Users could enter an Excel formula like `=1+2+3+4+5`, then click on the `Format` button to see the formatted formula.

What is odd is that, after clicking on `Format` button, a random part of the formula is often highlighted in gray:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what may be the cause?

PS: The current options setting are as follows:

```
const monacoOptions: monacoEditor.editor.IEditorConstructionOptions = {
  lineNumbers: 'off',
  selectionHighlight: false,
  glyphMargin: false, //left side,
  lineDecorationsWidth: 0, // width between line number and content,
  renderIndentGuides: false, // no indent guide lines
  minimap: { enabled: false },
};
```

Comment: By random you mean all the numeric values?

Comment: No, it is just random. See the first image, ` \n  + 5` is automatically highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I saw the green foreground and didn't notice the gray background at first. Will look at it more later.

Comment: I don't see any selection in either Chrome or Firefox, which I did not create myself. I activated the button on top, then typed in the text from your sshot and finally clicked `Format`.

Comment: Is there any chance for you to share some code in a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the value of the model ie `editor.getModel().setValue('FORMATTED-CODE')` you should have to set the position of the cursor manually.

The selection is actually not random. Monaco will select all the extra texts you have added. For example - 
Before : `1+2+3+4+5` - here last position is line 1 column 10 
Format: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5` - here last position is line 1 column 18 
So the extra text  `+ 4 + 5` is selected, it means column 11 to 18 is selected

##### To set the position of the cursor at where it was before

```
const pos = editor.getPosition()
editor.getModel().setValue('FORMATTED-CODE')
editor.setPosition(pos)
```

##### To set the position of the cursor at `Line 1 Column 1`

```
editor.getModel().setValue('FORMATTED-CODE')
editor.setPosition({ lineNumber: 1, column: 1 })
```

##### To set the position of the cursor at last (using offset)

```
const formatted = 'FORMATTED-CODE'
const offset = formatted.length
const pos = editor.getModel().getPositionAt(offset)

editor.getModel().setValue(formatted)
editor.setPosition(pos)
```

##### You can also set selection

```
editor.setSelection({
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 1,
  endLineNumber: 1,
  endColumn: 5,
})
```

For more informations you can follow these APIs -

- [setPosition](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditor.html#setposition) - To set cursor position
- [setSelection](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditor.html#setselection) - To set selection
- [setSelections](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditor.html#setselections) - To set multiple positions & selections